# Add 'inactive' mouse listener

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

**Mr Korbel was dead on, Thank you very much**

I have a mouse listener on a `JPanel` and its working properly. I'm trying to add some rollover support to a `JLabel` but when I add the mouse listener to the JLabel the `JPanel`'s mouse listener stops receiving events when the label's mouse listener receives events.

I just want to add a mouse listener to the JLabel without blocking the mouse listener of the `JPanel` under it. Thanks.

**Bonus problem**! I would like to do `getComponentAt(Point p)` and get the component on the botton, not the topmost, any suggestions? I have a workaround for this so this part isn't important but I dislike workarounds. Thanks again.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: For the "bonus problem" you should have a new posting. It gets too complicated discussing multiple issues in the same posting.

Comment: No thanks to Andrew and at cami it's not a major problem so I just tacked it on in case I could get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please is your `JLabel` moveable/dragable, in other cases your question doesn't make me real sence because deepest `JComponenet` in the hierarchy take Focus / MouseListeners by default, anyway look at [SwingUtilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html), there are methods can returns relative coordinates to the parent

Comment: Thanks. yea it is movable. I'll follow your link.

Comment: That was it. I Tried using getComponent.getParent.... but I got NPE when I dragged out. With that I can drag out and I dont have to have the parent handle the dragging soooo yea, nailed it.

Answer (score 2):

> but when I add the mouse listener to the JLabel the JPanel's mouse listener stops receiving events when the label's mouse listener receives events.

Yes, this is the way mouse event handling works. Only the first component that has a listener will receive the event. It wouldn't be very efficient to keep passing the event up the component hierarchy to each component.

> I just want to add a mouse listener to the JLabel without blocking the mouse listener of the JPanel under it.

You can handle this in the mouse listener attached to the label and then redispatch the event to the parent panel. Check out the `dispatchEvent(...)` of the `Component` class in the API for more information.